# Get all environment variables of a Docker container including security variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to get all environment variables that a Docker image accepts? Including authentications and all possible ones to make the best out of that image?

For example, I've run a `redis:7.0.8` container and I want to use every possible feature this image offers.
First I used `docker inspect` and saw this:

```
            "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "GOSU_VERSION=1.16",
            "REDIS_VERSION=7.0.8",
            "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-7.0.8.tar.gz",
            "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA=06a339e491306783dcf55b97f15a5dbcbdc01ccbde6dc23027c475cab735e914"
        ],
```

I also tried `docker exec -it my-container env` which just showed me the same thing. I know there are more variables, for example this doesn't include the following:

```
REDIS_PASSWORD
REDIS_ACLS
REDIS_TLS_CERT_FILE
```

Comment: They _accept_ any env var at all, but they won't _respond to_ all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent documentation, this is pretty much impossible.

Let's start by repeating @jonrsharpe's comment:

> They *accept* any env var at all, but they won't *respond* to all of them.

Consider this Python code, for example:

```py
import os

def get_environ(d, name):
  d.get(name, 'absent')

foo = os.environ.get('FOO', 'default_foo')
star_foo = get_environ(os.environ, foo)
print(star_foo)
```

This fragment looks up an environment variable `$FOO`.  You could probably figure that out, if you knew the main process was in Python and recognized `os.environ`.  But then it passes that value and the standard environment to a helper function, which looks up that environment variable by name.  You'd need detailed static analysis to understand this is actually also an environment-variable lookup.

```shellsession
$ ./test.py
absent
$ default_foo=bar ./test.py
bar
$ FOO=BAR BAR=quux ./test.py
quux
$ I=3 ./test.py
absent
```

(A fair bit of the code I work with accesses environment variables rather haphazardly; it's not just "find the main function" but "find every `ENV` reference in every file in every library".  Some frameworks like Spring Boot make it possible to set hundreds of configuration options via environment variables, and even if it were possible to get every possible setting here, the output would be prohibitive.)

"What environment variables are there" isn't standard container metadata.  You'd have to identify the language the main container process runs, and do this sort of analysis on it, including compiled languages.  That doesn't seem like a solvable problem.